pyTelegramBotApi не работает Callback для одного бота а для другого работает
Помогите пож. Запусакю простой код для одного бота работает для второго нет в чем может быть причина, второй бот на нажатию кнопки ни как не реагирует, тупо идет типо загрузка и в логах ничего нет. все в одном месте тупо меняю токен. Дуриге функции обоих ботов работают. Боты на разных аккаунтах.
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def starts(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Click me!', callback_data='button_click')
    markup.add(button)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello! This is an inline keyboard example.', reply_markup=markup)
 
# Define the callback function for the inline keyboard button
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    print('dsfds')
    if call.data == 'button_click':
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text='Button clicked!')
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Button clicked!')


поменял токен бота заработало если у кого будет такая проблема

Не раз встречающийся баг у телеграм. Старый токен можно будет удалять сразу. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876048/telegram-inline-keyboard-button-not-working/62913374#comment138718998_62913374
